# merge two lists into one multidimensional list in python

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array, merge

I would like to merge these two lists in python

```
a = [(Test,Name),(D1,value1),(D2,value2),(D3,Value3)]

b = [(D1,value-n1),(D2,value-n2),(D2,value-n3)]
```

to the new list

```
new_list = [(Test,Name),(D1,value1,value-n1),(D2,value2,value-n2),(D3,Value3,value-n3)]
```

I am able to merge them with the zip() but the values are getting added to the first element which i don't want.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried with `zip()`?

Comment: So you want that tuples inside the original list that start with the same element will be combined to one tuple in the result list (without duplicating the first element)?

Comment: @Mark You do not specify if the lists are variable length, if there could be more than 2 occurrences of one "key". We need a few more details please. Also is there a typo? Should it not be **(D3, value-n3)** in b?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

a = [("Test","Name"),("D1","value1"),("D2","value2"),("D3","Value3")]
b = [("D1","value-n1"),("D2","value-n2"),("D3","value-n3")]

merged = OrderedDict()

for list_ in a, b:
    # default dict like
    for k, v in list_:
        try:
            merged[k].append(v)
        except:
            merged[k] = [v]
# merge the keys and values (list)
merged_list = [(k,) + tuple(v) for k, v in merged.items()]
print(merged_list)
# [('Test', 'Name'), ('D1', 'value1', 'value-n1'), ('D2', 'value2', 'value-n2'), ('D3', 'Value3', 'value-n3')]
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach will assume that there are no duplicate first elements in tuples inside the same original list.

```
a = [("Test","Name"),("D1","value1"),("D2","value2"),("D3","Value3")]
b = [("D1","value-n1"),("D2","value-n2"),("D2","value-n3")]

b_lookup = {t[0]: t[1:] for t in b}
c = []

for tup in a:
    if tup[0] in b_lookup:
        c.append(tup + b_lookup.pop(tup[0]))  # also removes element from b_lookup
    else:
        c.append(tup)

print(c)
```

Output:

```
[('Test', 'Name'), ('D1', 'value1', 'value-n1'), ('D2', 'value2', 'value-n3'), ('D3', 'Value3')]
```

Comment: You could simply use: b_lookup = dict(b)

Comment: @AliSAIDOMAR You are right under the condition that we may safely assume that all tuples in the input lists have an exact length of 2 items. But I preferred to write a more flexible solution.

Answer (score 0):

With `zip` + `list comprehension`

```
a[:1] + [(w, x, z) for ((w, x), (y, z)) in zip(a[1:], b)]
```

Comment: You are assuming that you always want your list to start with the first element of a, and that there cannot be another element in b with "Test" as the first part of the tuple.

Comment: @Remuze you are right, but from the question it seems to me that the data will be in the same format, otherwise OP must have specified it. Why bother handling the cases that will never be there and make the code more complex?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to merge two lists of tuples, where the first item in each tuple is a key, combining tuples when keys match.

If you don't care about the sorting of the outcome:

```
from collections import defaultdict
>>> c = defaultdict(list)
>>> a = [('Test','Name'),('D1','value1'),('D2','value2'),('D3','Value3')]
>>> b = [('D1','value-n1'),('D2','value-n2'),('D3','value-n3')]
>>> for k, v in a: c[k].append(v)
...
>>> for k, v in b: c[k].append(v)
...
>>> new_list = list(c.iteritems())
>>> new_list
[('Test', ['Name']),
 ('D2', ['value2', 'value-n2']),
 ('D3', ['Value3', 'value-n3']),
 ('D1', ['value1', 'value-n1'])]
```

Comment: The question does not state that the not-first elements of each tuple inside the return list shall be grouped together in an other list. Instead the example output contains only two hierarchy levels.

Answer (score -2):

[image: Example]

```
>>> a = [("a",1),("b",2)]
>>> b = [("c",3),("b",4)]
>>> c = a+b
>>> c
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('b', 4)]
```

Comment: This does not produce his desired output.